# implementing binary Search tree reconstruction from preOrder array in Java?

Tags: java, c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, preorder

I have followed [this idea](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=14419694) and this [C++ code](http://ideone.com/VohnS) to reconstruct binary Search Tree from PreOrder array in Java. I am not reinventing the algorithm, but trying to implement pseudocode.
I need help here. I do not get the correct output. The output I get is below the code.

```
public class BinaryTreeMethods {           
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {7,5,3,6,9,8,10};
        Node newone = CreateFromPreOrder(arr,arr.length);
            printInorder(newone);
            System.out.println();
            printPreOrder(newone);

public static Node CreateFromPreOrder(int[] arr, int length) {

            if(length==0)
               return null;
            Node root = new Node(arr[0]);
            Stack<Node> s = new Stack<Node>();
            s.push(root);
            for(int i=1; i<length; i++)
            {

            Node tmp = new Node(arr[i]);
            Node next = s.peek();
            if(tmp.data < next.data)
            {
            next.left = tmp;
            }
            else
            {
            Node popped = null;
            while(!s.isEmpty() && tmp.data > next.data)
            {
            popped= s.peek();
            s.pop();
            }
            popped.right = tmp;
            }
            s.push(tmp);
            }
            return root;
            }
     public static void printInorder(Node root) {

            if (root!=null){
                printInorder(root.left);
                System.out.print(" " + root.data);
                printInorder(root.right);
            }
        }

class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    int data;

    public Node(int c){
        this(c, null, null);
    }
    public Node(int c,Node left, Node right) {
        this.data = c;
        this.left=left;
        this.right=right;
    }


}




     public static void printInorder(Node root) {

            if (root!=null){
                printInorder(root.left);
                System.out.print(" " + root.data);
                printInorder(root.right);
            }
        }


public static void printPreOrder(Node root) {

            if (root!=null){
                System.out.print(" " + root.data);
                printInorder(root.left);
                printInorder(root.right);
            }
        }
            }
```

I do not get the expected output:

```
3 5 7 6 8 9 10
 7 3 5 6 8 9 10
```

Comment: You should be calling `printPreOrder`recursively. You are calling `printInorder` instead, so your calls are not recursive.

Comment: @meghamind: my calls are recursive. the input array is given in preOrder and the output I print (both inOrder and PreOrder) should match my input PreOrder array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the recursive printing is messed up. Here `printPreOrder` should be calling itself to traverse left and right subtrees than calling `printInOrder` to do the traversal.

```
public static void printPreOrder(Node root) {

            if (root!=null){
                System.out.print(" " + root.data);
                printPreOrder(root.left); 
                printPreOrder(root.right);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please see my updated code..I forgot to paste method for PrintPreOrder previously. also look at my comment above

Comment: I was referring to the `printPreOrder` method  posted. It doesn't seem to be calling **itself** recursively - instead it calls `printInorder(root.left);`

Comment: Thank you, I got what you mean..you are correct..fixing this works now..stupid me..

Answer (score 1):

Using explicit stack is like over complicating the code, so would rather go with recursion which is pretty easy to grasp. Just recessively calculate the `min`, `max` and the index which is indicating the current pointer in the array.

```
TreeNode createTree(int[] a, Index i, int min, int max) {
    if (i.index >= a.length) {
        return null;
    }
    if (a[i.index] > min && a[i.index] < max) {
        int current = a[i.index];
        TreeNode t = new TreeNode(a[i.index]);
        i.index = i.index + 1;
        t.left = createTree(a, i, min, current);
        t.right = createTree(a, i, current, max);
        return t;
    }
   return null;
}
```

where `Index` class is given below:

```
class Index {

    int index;

    Index(int k) {
        index = k;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have implemented using recursion. but I wanted to get the stack method working as cited by many people in the link I provided. may be I should stick with recursion..what is the complexity here. It is O(n) correct..

Comment: Thanks, As pointed by the answer below, I messed up my recursive call for printing, fixing it makes it work now..